# Why can't I sent data from POST to a form on the next rendered page using Nodejs and Express?

Tags: node.js, post, express, get

I'm pretty new to Nodejs -  I'm trying to pass a user's email to a form on the next page after they successfully login. The login authentication is fine, but when it loads the next page the input where the email should be is still blank.

I checked my console logs and my the email string is definitely defined.
What am I missing?

**dashboard.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <% include ../partials/header.ejs %>
</head>
<body>
<% include ../partials/nav.ejs %>

<div class = "jumbotron">

    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <h2>Profile</h2>
    <form action="login" method="get">
            Email: <input class="readonly" input type="text" name="email" readonly>
    </form>

 <div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
// Login Authentication
app.post('/login', function(request, response) {
    var email = request.body.email;
    var password = request.body.password;

    console.log("post received: %s %s", email, password);

    var query = 'SELECT * FROM Users WHERE email = \'' + email + '\'' + 'AND password = \'' + password + '\'';

    pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
        client.query(query, function(err, result) {
            done();

            var numRows = result.rows.length;
            console.log("Row count: %d", result.rows.length)
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                response.send("Error: Could not execute query" + err);
            } else {
                if (numRows == 0) {
                    response.render('pages/loginerrorindex');
                } else {
                    request.session.user = email;
                    request.session.admin = true;
                    console.log("Sending email to dash: %s", email);
                    response.render('pages/dashboard', { email: email });
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I thought the following line in the above code would work, but it doesn't seem to be passing info to the form

```
 response.render('pages/dashboard', {email: email} );
```

Comment: Could you please share the HTML template for `pages/dashboard`?

Comment: sure! i just edited the above. dashboard.ejs is pages/dashboard

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see you using the `email` variable anywhere in the template?

Comment: var email = request.body.email is defined by a previous login page, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: shouldn't this line take in the email as input? Email: <input class="readonly" input type="text" name="email" readonly>

Comment: Check my answer. `readonly` HTML attribute should only be used when you want to prevent the user from being able to change information in your `input` tag, i.e., your tag is now read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rendering a template (using *EJS*, *Handlebars*, *Jade*, etc.) along with a data context, you need to also specify **where** you want to embed the information stored in your data context in your template.

In your case, you are rendering your template like so:

```
response.render('pages/dashboard', {
    email: email
});
```

The object `{email: email}` is your data context for the template.

Now in your template file, you want to be able to display the `email` property from your data context.

Here's how to do that:

```
<%= email %>
```

The markup `<%= email %>` is used in EJS to embed the `email` information from your data context into your template.

So, you need to use this markup in your `pages/dashboard` template in order to display the email.

---

Check out more info on the EJS markup in the [docs](https://github.com/mde/ejs#tags).

Comment: this works like a charm! you're the best - thank you for the clear explanation and for also providing a link to the relevant documentation :)

Comment: @Jcr Always ready to help! Please accept and/or upvote the answer :)